# How to achieve low latency on MediaLive & MediaStore

Tags: amazon-web-services, latency, aws-media-live, aws-mediastore, aws-mediapackage

I am using MediaLive & MediaStore to stream Live content facing a delay of 18sec, Need Help.

Using the following configurations

**MediaLive -Input details**

Input type -> RTMP (push)

Input destinations Channel class-> STANDARD

Network mode -> PUBLIC

**MediaLive -channel**

General input settings

Source End Behavior: CONTINUE

Input Filter: AUTO

Filter Strength: 1

Deblock Filter: Disabled

Denoise Filter: Disabled

SMPTE-2038 Data Preference: IGNORE

**Channel and input details**

Channel template: HTTP live streaming

Channel class: STANDARD

Input specifications: Input codec(VAC), Input resolution(HD), Maximum input bitrate (MAX_20_MBPC)

**Output groups**

HLS group destination A: mediastoressl://----------------.data.mediastore.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/path/main

HLS group destination A: mediastoressl://----------------.data.mediastore.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/path/main

**HLS settings**

CDN Setting: Hls Basic Push

Connection Retry Interva: 30

Num Retries: 5

Filecache Duration: 300

Restart Delay: 5

Input Loss Action: EMIT_OUTPUT

**Location**

Directory Structure: SINGLE_DIRECTORY

Segments Per Subdirectory: 10000

**Manifest and Segments**

Output Selection: MANIFESTS_AND_SEGMENTS

Mode: LIVE

TS File Mode: SEGMENTED_FILES

Stream Inf Resolution: INCLUDE

Manifest Duration Format: FLOATING_POINT

Segment Length: 1

Num Segments: 3

Keep Segments: 3

Min Segment Length: ---

Segmentation Mode: USE_SEGMENT_DURATION

I-Frame Only Playlists: DISABLED

Program Date Time: INCLUDE

Program Date Time Period: 600

Client Cache: ENABLED

Timestamp Delta Milliseconds: ---

Codec Specification: RFC_4281

Manifest Compression: NONE

Redundant Manifest: DISABLED

**DRM**
Include IV in Manifest - INCLUDED

IV Source: FOLLOWS_SEGMENT_NUMBER

I am using https://obsproject.com/download OBS Player for Input Stream & VLC to output stream m3u8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inquiry! Please be aware that AWS MediaServices do not implement any specifications the industry is developing for standardizing low latency OTT delivery though there are ways of reducing overall latency by other means.

You might try looking into these helpful guides on achieving lower realized latency:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/how-to-compete-with-broadcast-latency-using-current-adaptive-bitrate-technologies-part-1/

https://pages.awscloud.com/rs/112-TZM-766/images/GEN_elemental-wp-achieving-low-latency.pdf